# Kotlin for Android development: Text field to TextView?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, textview

I started learning to develop Android applications in Kotlin two weeks ago. I'm currently trying to make some changes to my tip calculator application and am trying to display the text field input into a totalCost TextView (where you see the "Cost of Service" text below the "Tip Amount: $20.00"), but I've no idea how to go about doing that.

[Click here to see the app layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl5iS.png)

And here's the code:

#### File *activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_cost_of_service"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_store"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/cost_of_service"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/cost_of_service"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/cost_of_service"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/cost_of_service"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/icon_cost_of_service"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/cost_of_service_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_service_question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_service"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/service_question"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/service_question"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/service_question"
        style="@style/Widget.TipTime.TextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/how_was_the_service"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/cost_of_service"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cost_of_service" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/tip_options"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checkedButton="@id/option_twenty_percent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/service_question"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/service_question">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/option_twenty_percent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/amazing_service" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/option_eighteen_percent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/good_service" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/option_fifteen_percent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ok_service" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_round_up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_round_up"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/round_up_switch"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/round_up_switch"/>


    <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
        android:id="@+id/round_up_switch"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/round_up_tip"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/icon_round_up"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tip_options" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculate_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calculate"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/round_up_switch"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/round_up_switch" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tip_result"
        style="@style/Widget.TipTime.TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/calculate_button"
        tools:text="Tip Amount: $10" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### File *MainActivity.kt*

```
package com.example.tiptime

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.tiptime.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.text.NumberFormat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.calculateButton.setOnClickListener { calculateTip() }
    }

    fun calculateTip() {
        val stringInTextField = binding.costOfServiceEditText.text.toString()
        val cost = stringInTextField.toDoubleOrNull()
        if (cost == null) {
            binding.tipResult.text = ""
            return
        }

        val tipPercentage = when (binding.tipOptions.checkedRadioButtonId) {
            R.id.option_twenty_percent -> 0.20
            R.id.option_eighteen_percent -> 0.18
            else -> 0.15
        }

        var tip = tipPercentage * cost
        if (binding.roundUpSwitch.isChecked) {
            tip = kotlin.math.ceil(tip)
        }

        val formattedTip = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(tip)
        binding.tipResult.text = getString(R.string.tip_amount, formattedTip)
    }

}
```

Comment: You've already done the hard work in ``calculateTip``! Just need to add the tip to the cost and display that amount in another ``TextView`` eh

Comment: That's the hard part XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get text from edit text box you can do the following:

```
    val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.cost_of_service_edit_text)
    val textValue = text.text.toString()
```

And to set text to a textView you would do:

```
    val textView = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.textViewId)
    textView.text = textValue
```

Comment: Thanks! I added the following code:

`val editText = findViewById< EditText >( R.id.cost_of_service_edit_text )
val textValue = editText.text.toString()

val textView = findViewById<EditText>( R.id.cost_of_service_edit_text )
textView.text = textValue`

There was a "Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Editable! was expected" for the textView when I ran it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try changing `textView.text = textValue` to `textView.setText(textValue)` Does this work?

Comment: I replaced the code as suggested, I run the program in an Android Virtual Device (AVD), and there are no errors. Great! but the TextView isn't showing up in the app (not sure if this is a problem with the activity_main.xml or strings.xml?)

Comment: Hmm.. Not sure if I can help with that one, as I would need more details, but If you are really stuck then you can ask another question, and I'll try and answer it :) Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks, your help was invaluable!